# set special mouse button to toggle between selection modes

Tags: shortcut

I have a mouse with two additional buttons and I wanted to create shrtcuts for them. I succecfully managed to make one toggle between solid/wireframe view and the other to toggle between edit/object mode, but I wanted to set the second one to toggle between selection modes (so that if I pressed it while in vertex selection mode, I would get edge selection mode, if in edge, get faces, if in faces, get vertex). All I managed was to make it set one of them on and off, regardless of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cycle through the possible selection options, you will need an operator that looks at the current selection to choose which selection option should be enabled.

That can be done in a simple operator, which you can then assign to your mouse button.

```
class SelectCycle(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'mesh.select_cycle'
    bl_label = 'Cycles through selection modes.'

    def execute(self, context):
        ts = context.tool_settings
        if ts.mesh_select_mode[0]:
            ts.mesh_select_mode = [False,True,False]
        elif ts.mesh_select_mode[1]:
            ts.mesh_select_mode = [False,False,True]
        else:
            ts.mesh_select_mode = [True,False,False]
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

You can find a copy of this as an addon [here](https://gist.github.com/sambler/a2cc6c7576321bc9210d3034a51a8baa), so you can enable it in your startup.blend.

In your input settings, you just need to enter `mesh.select_cycle` for the idname and choose the mouse button.

[image: adding a shortcut]

Comment: Wow... If anyone uses this, there is a bonus - if you use this in object mode, it switches to edit mode instead. Maybe this is not intentional, but it's really nice

Comment: That won't be from this code. Maybe you already have that button set to switch to edit mode.

Comment: oh, you're right, sorry for chaos

Comment: @sambler which key it works. I have activated the addon. Thanks